# Facebook post wirth php error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

i want to post from my website to my facebook site. i have created a app for my site. I use this code (i replace data from my app with '[]'):

```
require_once 'lib/php-graph-sdk-5.4/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

// initialize Facebook class using your own Facebook App credentials
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/#install
$access_token = '[aaccesstoken]';

$config = array();
$config['app_id'] = '[appid]';
$config['app_secret'] = '[appsecret]';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook($config);

// define your POST parameters (replace with your own values)
$params = array(
    "access_token" => $access_token, // see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
    "message" => "Test Message",
    "link" => "http://www.frauen-styles.de",
    "picture" => "http://www.frauen-styles.de/site/assets/files/3545/20.jpg",
    "name" => "Test Name",
    "caption" => "Caption",
    "description" => "Beschreibung"
);

// post to Facebook
// see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
try {
    $ret = $fb->post('/me/feed', $params);
    echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

what i'm doing wrong? im administrator of the page. support tells me that no publish_pages is requiered for the app for admins. I only want to send a post from my website to my facebook-page.

Comment: Hi, Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> support tells me that no publish_pages is requiered

As you can read in the API reference in the official docs, you do need `publish_pages` and `manage_pages` to post to a Page (as Page).

Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#publish